# Get a node list which contains all Nodes who's child nodes count is 0

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file

```
<RTT>
    <AgencyList>
        <agency Name="Bart" Ditection="Outbound">
            <RouteList>
                <Route Name="Fremont" Direction="test">
                    <Stop ID="25" Name="BayFare"/>
                </Route>
                <Route Name="SFO" Direction="Test"/>
                <Route Name="SFO" Direction="Test"/>
            </RouteList>
        </agency>
    </AgencyList>
</RTT>
```

**I would like to know how to get a node list which contains all the Route which has no child nodes *using C#***.

E.g The Node list should contain only

```
<Route  Name="SFO" Direction "Test">
<Route  Name="SFO" Direction "Test">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XPATH expression: `//Route[not(node())]` will address those `Route` elements.

It can be used in C# with something like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("RTT.xml"); //adjust correct path/filename

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("//Route[not(node())]");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  //Do something with the selected elements
}
```